# Accessing same Serial Port object in Matlab from two different files

Tags: matlab, user-interface, serial-port

I have a GUI which creates a serial port object when loaded and also sends some data through.. Now on pressing a button another math script file is executed which, based on some conditions it will be sending some other data to the same serial port. Now since we cannot initialize serial port object twice. How should I send data to serial port from the called function?

I tried to send the serial port object as parameter to the called function but that doesn't work

Similar case with Video Object !!

Upon loading, the GUI creates a video object for preview on SCADA screen.. now the called function should do image processing by grabbing images from the SAME video object. Even here, sending object as parameter isn't working..!!

Any solutions ???

Comment: I think that sharing the same serial object is the way to go. Why do you say it doesnt work? Show your code

Answer (score 0):

There was a small error in syntax of sending Serial Object as parameter.

For video object..

I initially set the `triggerconfig` to inf so that the video is displayed continuously on the GUI . But when I passed the videoobject as parameter, the called function has trigger again which is causing the error. Instead I replaced it with `getsnapshot()` and everything worked absolutely fine